# ClojureScript: TypeError: $jscomp.inherits is not a function

Tags: clojurescript

I have three imports from node_modules:

```
["web3" :as Web3js]
["web3modal" :default Web3Modal]
["@walletconnect/web3-provider" :default WalletConnectProvider]
```

If I comment out `web3` and `@walletconnect/web3-provider` then everything is ok, but when I try to import these two libs I receive an error in the console: **Failed to load woodenstaking_ui/components/connect_btn.cljs TypeError: $jscomp.inherits is not a function**

Before it was working without problems, I don't understand what happened, why they stopped working. The problem appeared after importing another library from npm, but I already removed it, removed node_modules folder, made again `npm install`, but it did not help.

Comment: This should be fixed in recent versions. Which version is this using and what `:target` in your build config?

Comment: :target :browser, clojurescript "1.10.773", shadow-cljs "2.11.0"

Answer (score 7):

1. stop shadow-cljs
2. remove the .shadow-cljs folder and your :output-to folder
3. restart shadow-cljs

Comment: In case this doesn't work, you can also try running `npm install` on your project after removing the specified directories.