# Uncaught TypeError: $jscomp.inherits is not a function

Tags: clojurescript, shadow-cljs

I'm getting this error while trying to build a Clojurescript project with shadow-cljs. The error is happening with the optimization level set to simple.

The full output in the browser console looks like this:

```
js.js:74 shadow-cljs - failed to load 34
shadow.js.jsRequire @ js.js:74
shadow$provide.<computed> @ index.js:5
shadow.js.jsRequire @ js.js:66
shadow$provide.<computed> @ index.js:8
shadow.js.jsRequire @ js.js:66
shadow$provide.<computed> @ index.js:6
shadow.js.jsRequire @ js.js:66
shadow.js.require @ js.js:113
(anonymous) @ index.js:2
(anonymous) @ append.js:2
js.js:74 shadow-cljs - failed to load 49
shadow.js.jsRequire @ js.js:74
shadow$provide.<computed> @ index.js:8
shadow.js.jsRequire @ js.js:66
shadow$provide.<computed> @ index.js:6
shadow.js.jsRequire @ js.js:66
shadow.js.require @ js.js:113
(anonymous) @ index.js:2
(anonymous) @ append.js:2
js.js:74 shadow-cljs - failed to load 124
shadow.js.jsRequire @ js.js:74
shadow$provide.<computed> @ index.js:6
shadow.js.jsRequire @ js.js:66
shadow.js.require @ js.js:113
(anonymous) @ index.js:2
(anonymous) @ append.js:2
js.js:74 shadow-cljs - failed to load 148
shadow.js.jsRequire @ js.js:74
shadow.js.require @ js.js:113
(anonymous) @ index.js:2
(anonymous) @ append.js:2
index.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: $jscomp.inherits is not a function
    at Object.shadow$provide.<computed> (index.js:5)
    at shadow.js.jsRequire (js.js:66)
    at Object.shadow$provide.<computed> (index.js:5)
    at shadow.js.jsRequire (js.js:66)
    at Object.shadow$provide.<computed> (index.js:8)
    at shadow.js.jsRequire (js.js:66)
    at Object.shadow$provide.<computed> (index.js:6)
    at Object.shadow.js.jsRequire (js.js:66)
    at Object.shadow.js.require (js.js:113)
    at index.js:2
shadow$provide.<computed> @ index.js:5
shadow.js.jsRequire @ js.js:66
shadow$provide.<computed> @ index.js:5
shadow.js.jsRequire @ js.js:66
shadow$provide.<computed> @ index.js:8
shadow.js.jsRequire @ js.js:66
shadow$provide.<computed> @ index.js:6
shadow.js.jsRequire @ js.js:66
shadow.js.require @ js.js:113
(anonymous) @ index.js:2
(anonymous) @ append.js:2
favicon.ico:1 GET http://localhost:8000/favicon.ico 404 (File not found)
```

I've created an example repo that replicates what I'm seeing as simply as I can [here](https://github.com/ruhansh/shadow-example2).

I've tried clearing caches and whatnot as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64169633/clojurescript-typeerror-jscomp-inherits-is-not-a-function).

With optimizations set to advanced I don't get this problem but I get other bugs more randomly with harder to read stack traces. Since it seems likely that it's the same problem appearing in different ways and since this is easier to replicate I'm attempting to making things work in simple mode first. The errors I get in the full app with advanced compilation look like this:

```
core.cljs:2564 Uncaught TypeError: pe is not a function
    at Ib (core.cljs:2564)
    at Function.wn.b (set.cljs:56)
    at Nn.g._update_watching (ratom.cljs:408)
    at yn (ratom.cljs:62)
    at Qn (ratom.cljs:539)
    at c.render (component.cljs:271)
    at kg (react-dom.production.min.js:188)
    at qi (react-dom.production.min.js:187)
    at ak (react-dom.production.min.js:270)
    at Ni (react-dom.production.min.js:251)
Ib @ core.cljs:2564
wn.b @ set.cljs:56
g._update_watching @ ratom.cljs:408
yn @ ratom.cljs:62
Qn @ ratom.cljs:539
(anonymous) @ component.cljs:271
kg @ react-dom.production.min.js:188
qi @ react-dom.production.min.js:187
ak @ react-dom.production.min.js:270
Ni @ react-dom.production.min.js:251
me @ react-dom.production.min.js:251
Ag @ react-dom.production.min.js:244
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:124
e.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:19
cd @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
Oh @ react-dom.production.min.js:124
uc @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
Vc @ react-dom.production.min.js:238
enqueueForceUpdate @ react-dom.production.min.js:135
r.forceUpdate @ react.production.min.js:13
g.flush_render @ batching.cljs:39
g.flush_queues @ batching.cljs:98
g.run_queues @ batching.cljs:78
a @ batching.cljs:59
requestAnimationFrame (async)
g.schedule @ batching.cljs:59
mn @ batching.cljs:52
g.queue_render @ batching.cljs:64
pn @ batching.cljs:112
Qn.d.ob.d.Ja @ ratom.cljs:544
g._handle_change @ ratom.cljs:402
Hc @ ratom.cljs:345
Cn @ ratom.cljs:104
g.ua @ ratom.cljs:146
Qc @ core.cljs:864
qf @ core.cljs:4493
(anonymous) @ lobby.cljs:53
fa @ react-dom.production.min.js:53
ma @ react-dom.production.min.js:53
wa @ react-dom.production.min.js:54
nh @ react-dom.production.min.js:101
ih @ react-dom.production.min.js:102
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:114
$g @ react-dom.production.min.js:293
eb @ react-dom.production.min.js:51
eh @ react-dom.production.min.js:106
yb @ react-dom.production.min.js:76
ub @ react-dom.production.min.js:75
e.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:19
cd @ react-dom.production.min.js:123
rb @ react-dom.production.min.js:293
Fb @ react-dom.production.min.js:74
```

Interestingly these particular errors go away when I turn on pseudo-names.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is setting `:compiler-options {:output-feature-set :es6}`. `$jscomp.inherits` are the polyfills inserted by the Closure Compiler for transpiling `class` and other more "modern" constructs. Setting `:es6` will stop that from happening. This is the best option unless you need to care about ancient browser versions.

Thanks for setting up a reproducible example. I can reproduce it with `:simple`, setting it to `:advanced` however works just fine? I have a rough idea what is happening in `:simple` and will see how to fix it properly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Setting it to es6 also seems to fix the problem I was having with advanced compilation too.

Comment: I spoke too soon. I'm still seeing errors in advanced mode. Much better than before though.